# Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am using springboot to connect to a mysql database. Please find my configuration below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:<connection-url>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
```

Api code

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@GetMapping(value = "/validateuser/{consumerName}")
@Transactional
public Boolean valiadateuser(@PathVariable String consumerName) {
    LOGGER.info("Inside validateuser -1");
    ConsumerName user = consumerRepository.findByName(consumerName);
    LOGGER.info("Inside validateuser -2 :::: " + user);
    if (user != null) {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

Below is my exception

```
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:538) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:665) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:370) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.server.controller.SubscribeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14f090fd.subscribeTopic(<generated>) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `@Transactional`?

Comment: does @transactional, not ensure auto commit and auto closure of connection

Comment: @user7294900 I have removed the annotation, still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer

updated the resource.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:<connection-url>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same exception on my Spring / Postgres stack. Basically, the DB can not return/commit all the rows that match your query in time.

It can be fixed by creating indexes on the columns used in the particular query. This speeds the query up.

```
CREATE INDEX index_redflag_person
ON redflag_person (firstname, alias,lastname,address,birthplace);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Spring and Hibernate and PostgreSQL for practice, got the similar exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: 
Unable to commit against JDBC Connection] with root cause
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
```

my hibernate.prop has some config below

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_STATEMENT

packages.to.scan=org.practice.dao.entity
```

It's weird bcs the default hibernate.connection.autocommit value in hibernate 5.6 is [false](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-connection)

After a whole day search, I could not find the same error on the internet, finally I figured it out: somehow I added hibernate.connection.handling_mode in my config file, remove it(the default is fine) and the app works as expected

so maybe check the config and use the simplest param would help someone else